# Chrome 18 cannot view selected text in a disabled multi select box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have Chrome browser version 18. The following select box is disabled and the selected values in the box are not visible.

[image]

Code

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="opDays" id="opDays" style="height: 120px; width:120px;" disabled="disabled">

                        <option value="1">Sunday</option>

                        <option value="2">Monday</option>

                        <option value="3">Tuesday</option>

                        <option value="4">Wednesday</option>

                        <option value="5">Thursday</option>

                        <option value="6">Friday</option>

                        <option value="7">Saturday</option>

                    </select>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Show us some code. It's prolly `css` related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the colors in the picture, you have other styling besides the inline one. You should try inspecting the select element and check out the applied styles.

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/shVeq/6/

Try styling the `option[selected]` selector like this:

```
option[selected] { color: #fff;} ​
```

Comment: try putting this <option value="2" selected="true">Monday</option>
the selected text becomes invisible